# Symfony3: how to validate min image width OR height?

Tags: symfony

Standard Symfony's `Assert\Image` validator allows check `minWidth` AND `minHeight`. My goal is to reject images that have both width and height less than 1000px. If width or height is greater than 1000px, image should be valid. How to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a [custom constraint Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).

I would extend `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\ImageValidator` and `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image` by adding additional validation option like `minLargerDimention`.

Answer (score 1):

use the [`Callback`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) constraint:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Person.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;


class Person
{
    /**
     * @var File
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
        // get width and height from image
        $info = getimagesize($this->getImage());
        list($width, $height) = $info;

        // check if the name is actually a fake name
        if ($width < 1000 && $height < 1000) {
            $context->buildViolation('The image should have at least a width or height of 1000!')
                    ->atPath('image')
                    ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```